# Magento 2.2.0 - Unable to create voucher code

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, shopping-cart-price-rules

We have a weird problem with Magento where the client is trying to create a voucher code for customers with her logins, but this does not work. This is the error message she is getting.

[image: magento 2 error message]

We've even tried the same logins as the client and it works for us. She has tried using her 4G connection on her phone to create a voucher code but keeps getting the same problem.

Creating a new account doesn't seem to work either, sending her logins for our own account doesn't work either.

Current exception.log downloaded from the server;

```
[2018-04-17 10:18:32] main.CRITICAL: Invalid input date format '16/04/+00201818' {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Invalid input date format '16/04/+00201818' at /home/aatuco/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/DateTime/Filter/Date.php:69)"} []
[2018-04-17 10:23:00] main.CRITICAL: Invalid input date format '17/04/+00201818' {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Invalid input date format '17/04/+00201818' at /home/aatuco/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/DateTime/Filter/Date.php:69)"} []
[2018-04-17 15:07:14] main.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /home/aatuco/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category/Link/SaveHandler.php on line 122 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /home/aatuco/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category/Link/SaveHandler.php on line 122 at /home/aatuco/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"} []
[2018-04-25 16:10:53] main.CRITICAL: Invalid input date format '24/04/+00201818' {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Invalid input date format '24/04/+00201818' at /home/aatuco/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/DateTime/Filter/Date.php:69)"} []
[2018-05-08 10:56:52] main.CRITICAL: Invalid input date format '08/05/+00201818' {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Invalid input date format '08/05/+00201818' at /home/aatuco/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/DateTime/Filter/Date.php:69)"} []
[2018-05-08 11:04:43] main.CRITICAL: Invalid input date format '08/05/+00201818' {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Invalid input date format '08/05/+00201818' at /home/aatuco/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/DateTime/Filter/Date.php:69)"} []
[2018-05-21 09:17:59] main.CRITICAL: Invalid input date format '25/04/+00201818' {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Invalid input date format '25/04/+00201818' at /home/aatuco/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/DateTime/Filter/Date.php:69)"} []
[2018-05-21 09:30:18] main.CRITICAL: Invalid input date format '25/04/+00201818' {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Invalid input date format '25/04/+00201818' at /home/aatuco/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/DateTime/Filter/Date.php:69)"} []
[2018-05-21 10:50:03] main.CRITICAL: Invalid input date format '25/04/+00201818' {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Invalid input date format '25/04/+00201818' at /home/aatuco/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/DateTime/Filter/Date.php:69)"} []
[2018-05-21 10:51:26] main.CRITICAL: Invalid input date format '25/04/+00201818' {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Invalid input date format '25/04/+00201818' at /home/aatuco/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/DateTime/Filter/Date.php:69)"} []
[2018-05-21 11:25:56] main.CRITICAL: Invalid input date format '21/05/+00201818' {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Invalid input date format '21/05/+00201818' at /home/aatuco/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/DateTime/Filter/Date.php:69)"} []
```

Don't think that shows much in relation to the problem that we are having. I'll get the client to create a voucher code on the LIVE website and see if the log file is updated.

**I'm wondering if anyone else has come across this very strange problem?**

Comment: Can you check error log?

Comment: Check var/log/ error and add it in question

Comment: magento  some critical error happens on  save of cart rule.Goto Magento\SalesRule\Controller\Adminhtml\Promo\Quote\Save https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/SalesRule/Controller/Adminhtml/Promo/Quote/Save.php#L103  line changes `$this->messageManager->addError(
                    __('Something went wrong while saving the rule data. Please review the error log.')
                );`  to `$this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());` and see what error happending